# Istio Network Policy Logging

Tags: logging, kubernetes, devops, tracking, istio

Hello I have got a question about Istio Network Policies .

I created a network policy shown as below and tested it . It works .

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: api-policy
  namespace: point-1
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      run: api
  ingress:
  - ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
    from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          istio: ingress
```

In my case I want to log all requests all around the internal network , and track which request is blocked, denied according to the policy concerns ?

How Can I log the internal traffic activity in ISTIO .

Answer (score 1):

Istio deploys a envoy sidecar along with your pod and since all traffic goes through the envoy proxy you can get metrics and observability from envoy. You can follow Istio [docs](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/metrics/collecting-metrics/) on how to collect metrics. Also [envoy access logs](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/) can provide details of all http requests inside your mesh.